# ORA-01858: a non-numeric character issue in query

Tags: sql, oracle

So my sql query is to create grouping by date is as below.

```
select to_date(page_start_time,'DD-MM-YYYY') EventDate , count(case when page_title_to = 'Appointments' then event_id else null end) as Appointments
, count(case when page_title_to = 'User Login' then event_id else null end) as UserLogin
, count(case when page_title_to = 'Store Visit' then event_id else null end) as StoreVisit 
, count(case when page_title_to = 'Resume Store Visit' then event_id else null end) as ResumeStoreVisit 
, count(case when page_title_to = 'Visit History' then event_id else null end) as VisitHistory 
from MUD_SESSION_FLOWS
group by to_date(page_start_time,'DD-MM-YYYY') 
order by to_date(page_start_time,'DD-MM-YYYY') desc
```

This one fails with exception

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

If I change to_date to to_char then the query works fine. However, it does not really order by date but i guess by treating page_start_time as a string value. So, I don't get the right order of data. please advise how to fix it to order the data in the right order as well

Comment: What data type is `page_start_time`?

Comment: it's of type timestamp in db

Comment: Using `to_date()` on a `timestamp` is wrong. The `timestamp` will be first converted to a `varchar` value just to be converted back to a `date` again. And the implicit conversion from a `varchar` to a `date` is the reason for your error.

Comment: ok understood. so if i don't do that and keep it as to_char then in that case sorting is a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass a `date` or `timestamp` to the `to_date()` function.

If you want to group by day without the time part, use `trunc()`:

```
select to_char(trunc(page_start_time),'DD-MM-YYYY') EventDate, 
       count(case when page_title_to = 'Appointments' then event_id else null end) as Appointments, 
       count(case when page_title_to = 'User Login' then event_id else null end) as UserLogin, 
       count(case when page_title_to = 'Store Visit' then event_id else null end) as StoreVisit, 
       count(case when page_title_to = 'Resume Store Visit' then event_id else null end) as ResumeStoreVisit, 
       count(case when page_title_to = 'Visit History' then event_id else null end) as VisitHistory 
from MUD_SESSION_FLOWS
group by trunc(page_start_time)
order by trunc(page_start_time) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to round timestamp to date use ether [trunc(date)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) or [round(date)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions136.htm) function.